# Problem running ABP Web API within IIS Application (Virtual Directory)

Tags: iis, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I created an app with ASP.NET Boilerplate (ABP) using the Module Zero Core template (Angular and ASP.NET Core, except I'm using .NET Full Framework 4.x).  It works fine when I do a standard deployment to IIS (Angular running on port 80, ASP.NET Web API running on port 21021).  However, I'm running into trouble with the Swagger integration if I try to deploy the Web API to an IIS Application (similar to a virtual directory).  Previous answers I found have not provided a solution to the problem.

For example, the URL of the IIS Application is `http://example.com/myapi`. Navigating to that URL should redirect to `http://example.com/myapi/swagger`, but it redirects to `http://example.com/swagger` instead, which doesn't exist.  ServerRootAddress is set to `http://example.com/myapi` in appsettings.json.  This may be due to the following code in HomeController of the Web.Host project:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Redirect("/swagger");
}
```

It appears to be hard-coded to the root of the web site, rather than using a relative path, but I'm not certain.  If I modify the controller to use a relative path, the Swagger page will load, but I am not able to authenticate. It tries to navigate to `http://example.com/api/TokenAuth/Authenticate` instead of `http://example.com/myapi/api/TokenAuth/Authenticate`. Again, it is not using a relative path.  Here is related code from abp.swagger.js:

```js
xhr.open('POST', '/api/TokenAuth/Authenticate', true);
```

Is this a limitation of ABP or the Module Zero Core template, or is there some additional configuration I need to do in ABP, Swagger/Swashbuckle, or IIS to get this working? FWIW, the app is running on ABP version 3.8.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up changing ABP template code to use relative paths where necessary.

HomeController.cs:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Redirect("~/swagger");
}
```

abp.swagger.js:

```js
xhr.open('POST', '../api/TokenAuth/Authenticate', true);
...
xhrTenancyName.open('POST', '../api/services/app/Account/IsTenantAvailable', true);
```

More changes would be required in order to use SignalR.

A couple of changes were needed in the Angular app as well.

index.html:

```html
<base href="/myvirtualpath/">
```

sidebar-user-area.component.html:

```html
<img src="assets/images/user.png" width="48" height="48" alt="User" />
```

Comment: I have created the solution from ABP boilerplate and my files are somewhat different from yours. I have not managed to beat the error of incorrect bundle paths for IdentityServer project. Neither I can see where it's set - somewhere deep in guts... :(

Comment: @Alexander These changes were for ABP version 3.8. I'm not sure what is required for newer versions.